# Flask - Search db model by column

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using built in admin website of flask for searching data from db. So I created db model, and model view in which I specified *column_searchable_list*. When I enter search text, it will match this search text with each column in *column_searchable_list* [(1)](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/), and return list of matched rows.

This is cool, but sometimes it causes some unexpected result because some part of data from this column may match with part of data from other columns. Therefore, I wonder is there any way to implement search by specific column in flask. Or I have to create my own search tab. I am quite new to flask, so hope some of you guys know some tricks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the _apply_search method in your view to get a customized searching solution. I posted an example on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33269035/2800058) in response to a question about phrase searching in Flask-Admin.